# One single plot two different y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset consisting of three columns.
In a first step I plotted the column 1 and 2 as normal x,y plot.

```
fig = P.figure()
P.plot(x1, y1, label='test', ls='-', color='k', lw=2.0)
P.legend(loc=3)
P.grid(True)
P.xlabel(labelx, fontsize=20)
P.ylabel(labely, fontsize=20)    
P.axis([-4, 25, 300, 0])
P.xticks(fontsize=16)
P.yticks(fontsize=16)
P.savefig(os.path.join(output_dir,'{0}{1}.png'.format('figure_',root_name)),format='png')
P.close(fig)
```

Additionally, I would like to have the corresponding third column as a second y-axis (for the same plot!). I used twinx to create a second y-axis. I want the scale of the second y-Axis to automatically correspond to the first plot. I have no idea how to solve that. I would be thankful for any help.

To sum up, I would like to plot one dataset x and y1 and a corresponding third parameter as second y-axis (y2).

Comment: If you provide some code which shows us what you are trying to do then it is much easier to help you!

Comment: I put my code. Hope that helps.

Comment: So basically you want the second y axis to have the values (tick values that is) that are in the your third column (y2)?

Comment: Do you want to plot the y2 values using the second axis? if not then I cant really see why you want to plot the second y axis at all

Comment: jep exactly. but adjusted to the plot (x and y1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot both sets of data on the same figure you could use the following code

```
plt.plot(x,y1,x,y2)
```

Comment: I only want to plot the first dataset(x,y1) but want to visualise the corresponding third parameter values as a second y-axis.